# {"multicast_id":,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have stucked with google cloud message, I have two apps one for customer and other for admin. as i am getting

```
{"multicast_id":,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

> Configuration:
>
> Customer : Package : com.take.customer
>
> Admin    : Package : com.take.admin

Both Apps are added into on Firebase project in firebase console.

Admin app can send message to customer apps. but when customer app tries to send back the message getting notRegistered error message.

Both apps are using same FCM key. The registered ids are correct.  I have no clue what next.

Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Should not both app shall be using different FCM key?

Comment: @Saurabh is it ? But both belongs to the same firebase project

Comment: @SpeedRacer Did you manage to get it to work?